# >> and >>> operator with negative byte value in java

Tags: java, operators, byte, negative-number

I have a sample code snippet like this:

```
    byte a = -0b00001111;
    byte b = a;
    byte c = a;

    System.out.println("a=" + a );
    System.out.println("b=" + (b >> 1) );
    System.out.println("c=" + (c >>> 1) );
```

and, it prints:

a=-15

b=-8

c=2147483640

I don't quite understand how b and c became those 2 values respectively, could someone demonstrate me in steps how those 2 values were calculated please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For byte `a`, you have the literal `0b00001111`, which is binary for `15`, so `a` is `-15`.  The bit representation of `-15` for a `byte` is:

```
11110001
```

In Java, [unary numeric promotion occurs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) on the operands of bit-shift operators `<<`, `>>`, and `>>>`.

> Unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) is performed on each operand separately.

This means that the value is promoted to `int` before shifting.

The code `(b >> 1)` promotes `b` to an `int`, then shifts the value with sign extension.  This means that if the value was already negative, then a `1` bit is shifted to ensure it's still negative.

```
11110001
```

is promoted to

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11110001
```

which is `-15` as an `int`.  After shifting to the right one bit, with sign extension:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111000
```

which is `-8`.

However, for the code `(c >>> 1)`, the `>>>` unsigned right shift operator does *not* perform sign extension, even if the promotion to `int` does maintain the sign and the value.

```
11110001
```

is promoted to

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11110001
```

which is `-15` as an `int` as before.  After unsigned shifting to the right one bit:

```
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111000
```

The first bit is now `0`.  Without the most significant bit set, the value is now 2<sup>31</sup> - 8, or 2147483640.

Comment: sooo sorry about my belated "thanks"! Thanks for your detailed explanation which is very helpful!!